# function is not defined WordPress jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a js file with a function inside called showProduct.

In my HTML document I have a submit button which has this javascript:

```
onclick="showProduct(document.getElementById('suggest1').value);"
```

This gets the value of an input field with the id of suggest1 and is then passed 
 to the function showProduct. This works fine! But as soon as I add this before & after my jquery:

```
(function($) { .... })(window.jQuery);
```

I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: showProduct is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Any ideas on how I can get this to work? I need to put all the jQuery in this function to get it work with WordPress.

Thanks

Comment: *"I need to put all the jQuery in this function to get it work with WordPress"* – you don't, really. If you want to keep using `$` inside the function, the simplest fix is `var $ = jQuery;` as the first line inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an `on*` event attribute the function you're calling has to be in scope of the `window`. When you place your code in that IIFE that is no longer the case.

```
<button class="foo">Foo</button>
```

```js
(function($) {
  $('.foo').click(function() {
    var value = $('#suggest1').val();
    // do something with the value here...
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

One thing to note here is that the button click will submit any parent `<form>` elements, so you may need to instead hook to the `submit` event of that form if you do not want to submit it immediately.